# Broadcasting Logout

Tags: javascript, node.js

Someone posted something very similar to the following code on a thread about resources that I can no longer locate:

```
$scope.logout = function(){ 
    var outRes = $resource("/admin/logout"); 
    outRes.save({}, 
    function () { 
        $scope.userObject.lastActivity_type = "Log out"; 
        $rootScope.isLoggedIn = false; 
        $location.path("/login-register"); 
    }, 
    function errorHandling(err) {
        console.log("Not cool, error"); 
    }); 
}
```

It was super helpful for me on my assignment and seemed fairly recent so I was hoping to ask: could someone explain how to rewrite this with a broadcast method to let other users/every part of architecture know a user has logged out? The assignment's over and everything, I'm just curious

Comment: Is this for Angular.js 1? Looks like it but you don't mention it.

Comment: why broadcast ? if you logout you should transition to a different state/route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is for Angular 1, broadcasting an event makes it visible to all child scopes of the scope in which it is broadcast. If you want it to be visible to all scopes, you should broadcast it in the root scope, as in this example:

```
$rootScope.broadcast('my-event');
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) if you want some more information.

EDIT: I note that you also asked about broadcasting to other users. That's a very different kettle of fish!

Angular is purely a front-end framework so it can't broadcast a message to another client. If you wanted something like a chat or notification system whereby users received notification of changes made by other users in real time, you'd probably want to use websockets via a library like Socket.io. You'd send some kind of notification to the server, either via websockets or an AJAX request, and then on the server that would trigger broadcasting the message to those connected clients that should receive it. You can then use the method described above to trigger a corresponding event in the root scope of your Angular code. I won't go into the details for this as there's loads of tutorials on doing this with Socket.io.